# How to create an accessor in Vuex?

Tags: vuejs2, vuex, quasar

In Laravel we have Accessors that allow us to get manipulated data from a field or fields.

Is there an equivalent in Vuex? Specifically, I am using a component that takes a collection from Vuex and, for each item, displays `{{ item.title }}`.

However, `{{ item.title }}` doesn't exist and should be derived, on a collection by collection basis, when I get the data from Vuex. So it could be from `{{ item.name }}` or `{{ item.postcode }}` or whatever.

Is there any way I can do this?

Comment: I am still looking for a solution but for now I am just creating the accessors in Laravel and appending them to the JSON data. Hope this helps anyone.

Comment: I'm using `vuex-module-decorators` and its `getModule` function to gain access to the given store module. I added a read-only getter as an accessor for the internal property. Not sure how _legal_ this is, but it works.